# How to sample according to the square of a density?

Tags: probability, sampling

I meet the following question in sampling of probability distributions.

Assume that we know how to sample according to a given probability distribution with the density $f$, while $f$ is not analytically known. Denote by $(x_n)$ the obtained samples. I wonder whether it is possible to use these samples $(x_n)$ to sample according to the distribution with the density $Cf^2$ where $C$ is the normalisation constant. Thank you!

Comment: It is certainly possible to sample $x_n$ from $f$ and $y_n$ from $Cf^2\,.$ What do you mean by "use these samples" ?

Comment: I think some more information about the distribution is needed. Otherwise we can just let $y_n=x_n$ as this is consistent with a discrete (or "almost discrete") distribution $f$ with probability mass allocated uniformly over the observed values.

Comment: A technique from machine learning is to estimate $f$ as the (normalized) sum of $n$ normal distributions centered at the $x_n$, with some fixed $\sigma$ chosen a priori or heuristically.

Comment: I think your question is something like: "I have a button that, when pressed, gives me samples of a variable with density $f$. I would like to apply a transformation to those samples so that they are effectively samples from a variable with density $cf^2$." Did I get that right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have absolutely continuous random variable $X$ having density $f_X(x)$ and wish to find a transformation $g$ such that $Y=g(X)$ has density $f_Y(y)=C(f_X(y))^2.$ Hence, if you apply $g(\cdot)$ to each observation in your sample, the transformed sample is drawn according to the desired density.  Not sure how this can be done without knowing the analytic form for $f_X$ so let's assume you know it (e.g. using a parametric model).

---

Assuming $g$ is invertible, then the density of $Y=g(X)$ is given by

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{d}{dy}P(g(X)<y)=\frac{d}{dy}P(X<g^{-1}(y))=f_X(g^{-1}(y)){g^{-1}}' (y),$$

and equating to $C(f_X(y))^2$ tells us $z=g^{-1}(y)$ satisfies the differential equation

$$f_X(z)z'=C(f_X(y))^2,$$

which is solved by separation of variables:

$$z=F_X^{-1}\left(\int C(f_X(y))^2 dy\right),$$

where $F_X$ is the CDF of $X$.

---

Let's take an example: Suppose $X$ has CDF $F_X(x)=x^2$ (implying density $f_X(x)=2x$) on support $[0,1].$

Then we compute
$$g^{-1}(y)=F_X^{-1}\left(\int C(f_X(y))^2 dy\right)=\sqrt {\int C4y^2 dy}=\sqrt {\frac{4C}{3}y^3+k},\\
\implies g(x)=\left(\frac{3}{4C}(x^2-k)\right)^{1/3}$$

for any constant $k$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's hope of doing this in general. In particular, there's no *a priori* reason to believe that $f^2$ can be normalized to a new density function at all. (Example: consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}$ on $(0, 1)$.)